# Not able to install packages on RStudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio Server and trying to install basic packages and getting the below error -

g++ -I/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -

I../inst/include/ -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION    -fpic  -

DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATIN -O2 -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o

sh: g++: command not found

make: *** [Date.o] Error 127

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’

Does anyone face the same issue ? Please advise what needs to be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

> sh: g++: command not found

You should [install development tools suite](http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/06/28/install-build-essentials-for-centos-rhel-and-ubuntu/) first, then back to install the packag again.
On Ubuntu, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

On CentOS, you can try:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```